# Pass title property from main.component to the header.component in angular

Tags: angular

I have created a header component in my Angular project and want to pass the `{{title}}` property from my main app component into my header component so that the title of the app is alway visible inside the header component.

I added `@Input() title: string;` to the header component with the Input import in the core, then call the property `{{title}}` in the header html but it's blank. so I guess I'm missing something but not sure what?

Comment: Please, include the code for the relevant components and their templates in your post.

Comment: Are you including your header component inside main app component? could you please share the code?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided enough information. Below is the answer based on assumption that your header component is directly inside app component

**header.component.html**

```
Title = {{title}}
```

**header.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'header',
  templateUrl: 'header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HeaderComponent {
    @Input()
    title: string;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<header [title]="appTitle"></header>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
app.component.ts {
  appTitle = 'APP TITLE HERE';
}
```

If your header not directly inside app.component.html then you need to use

```
1. service to share the data between components
or
2. Pass title as a route data
or 
3. Pass title as a query param
```

**Note: Using service is best option here**

Comment: Thank you! i left out the [title]='title' in the <header> tag. :)

Comment: @Gavin if it works you can accept the answer and upvote

Answer (score 0):

In main Component

html file:

```
<header [title]="appTitle"></header>
```

In Header Component

ts file

```
export class HeaderComponent {
 @Input()
    title: string;
}
```